# How to set a default value of a nested message in Protocol Buffers?

Tags: protocol-buffers

If my proto file contains a code like this

```
message Inner {
    optional int32 someValue = 1;
}
message Outer {
    optional Inner innerMember = 2;
}
```

is it possible to set a default value of that innerMember, something like this?

`optional Inner innerMember = 2 [default = defaultValueForInner];`

If yes, what should I put at the place where is the `defaultValueForInner` to initialize it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only set the default value inside the Inner message itself:

```
message Inner {
    optional int32 someValue = 1 [default = 123];
}
message Outer {
    optional Inner innerMember = 2;
}
```

This means that if you use `Inner` from multiple places, the default will be the same for them all.

Comment: This is correct. There is no way to set a default value for a message field in Protobuf. (Cap'n Proto supports it, though.) (Disclosure: I am the author of both proto2 and Cap'n Proto.)